# list dictionary entry line by line

Tags: python, dictionary, printing, ftp

so i have this script to list files in my ftp server then to take the list and make a dictionary

```
 1 #!/usr/bin/env python3                                                                                                                                                                                        
 2 from ftplib import FTP                                                                                                                                                                                        
 3 host     = "localhost"                                                                                                                                                                                        
 4 user     = "chris"                                                                                                                                                                                            
 5 password = "qwerty"                                                                                                                                                                                           
 6 ftp      = FTP(host,user,password)                                                                                                                                                                            
 7 ftp.cwd("/home/chris")                                                                                                                                                                                        
 8 files = ftp.nlst()                                                                                                                                                                                            
 9 list_length = len(files)                                                                                                                                                                                      
10 #conversoin of list                                                                                                                                                                                           
11 def Convert(files):                                                                                                                                                                                           
12         it = iter(files)                                                                                                                                                                                      
13         res_dct = dict(zip(range(1,list_length), it))                                                                                                                                                         
14         return res_dct                                                                                                                                                                                        
15 print(Convert(files))
```

what I need to do is print the output of convert(files) where each file listed is a new line
eg:
1: 'Documents'
2: 'homework'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do You mean like this?

```
mydict = Convert(files)
for key in mydict:
    print(str(key) + ": " + mydict[key])
```

Comment: perfect i was wondering why my for whenever i tried that wasn't working I'm still brand new to programming and not very good. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I took your code, adapt it slightly to pythonify it a bit, + took the use case from ftplib doc, and it ran out of the box :

```
#https://docs.python.org/3/library/ftplib.html

from ftplib import FTP
ftp = FTP('ftp.us.debian.org')
ftp.login()
ftp.cwd("debian")
files = ftp.nlst()


def ls_to_dict(files):
    return dict(zip(range(1,len(files)),iter(files)))

print(ls_to_dict(files))
```